# Fetch the session object set in liferay theme java method into portlet doView() method

Tags: java, session, liferay, liferay-theme

i have a below method in theme:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)throws IOException,             ServletException {
  ((HttpServletRequest) request).getSession().setAttribute("test", "abc");
   }
```

i am trying to fetch above session object in doView method of portlet.

```
HttpSession httpSession =PortalUtil.getHttpServletRequest(renderRequest).getSession();
System.out.println("httpSession obj"+(String)httpSession.getAttribute("test"));
```

i even tried using as below :

```
HttpServletRequest request1 =PortalUtil.getHttpServletRequest(renderRequest);
HttpServletRequest originalRequest = PortalUtil.getOriginalServletRequest(request1);
HttpSession httpsession = originalRequest.getSession();
System.out.println("httpSession ==> " + httpsession);//session object gets printed
System.out.println("test "+httpsession.getAttribute("test"));//null
```

i get the null value when i try to fetch from doview method. Can anyone please suggest how to fetch the value from theme to portal

Answer (score 0):

You only get the `portletRequest` adapted to the `ServletRequest` interface. In addition you'll need `PortalUtil.getOriginalHttpServletRequest()`.

[Here's some more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8940078/what-is-the-difference-between-portalutil-getoriginalservletrequest-and-portalut/9030658#9030658) about the difference between the two.

Should you use it? No.

I can't imagine what the theme would need to write to the session. And the order of execution might not even be defined.

What should you use instead? I don't know as I font know what you're trying to achieve in the first place

Comment: Can you please guide me in my case should i use HttpSession httpSession =PortalUtil.getOriginalHttpServletRequest()(renderRequest).getSession();
System.out.println("httpSession obj"+(String)httpSession.getAttribute("test"));

Comment: the theme should write the session object value session.setAttribute("test", "abc"); as shown above. order of execution? this method is executed on the load of the theme. , i am trying to fetch that session object value test from theme to  doview()  method of portlet.

Comment: I can't imagine what problem this would solve. The theme should not have a lot of intelligence and it feels like any session interaction in the theme - especially writing to the session - is just plain wrong. Can you describe a real problem that you want to solve, instead of just checking if a test attribute can be read elsewhere?