# How to trigger auto login from Liferay MVC Porlet

Tags: java, authentication, liferay, portal

I have implemented auto-login in a hook so I can log in by sending login parameters in the url.

I'm trying to avoid a scenario where I have to send these parameters in plain text in the url. Is there a way to trigger the auto login from an MVCPortlet action method? I have tried setting the parameters in the action response but they are always null in the auto login hook's `login()` method.

Action class:

```
public void triggerLogin(ActionRequest actionRequest,
        ActionResponse actionResponse) {
    actionResponse.setRenderParameter("userEmail", user.getEmail());
    actionResponse.setRenderParameter("password", user.getPassword());
}
```

Login hook:

```
@Override
public String[] login(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AutoLoginException {

    String email = request.getParameter("userEmail"); // null
    String password = request.getParameter("password"); // null

    // email and password are null
}
```

I also tried setting it on the `HttpServletResponse` like so:

```
PortalUtil.getHttpServletResponse(
    actionResponse).setHeader("userEmail", user.getEmail());
```

Is there a way to do this without sending the password to the front end?

Answer (score 2):

There are several items here which are questionable - from a security standpoint the first one is that you seem to handle username/password in your own portlet - why you'd do this on a platform that handles all the identity management for you is beyond me, but you might have your reasons. I feel that this comment is called for, even in case you might have a good reason, because 95% of other reasons (of people reading this later) will not be good.

That being said, there's a [blade sample for an auto login](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-blade-samples/tree/master/liferay-workspace/extensions/auto-login) - this is easy to tweak to require a [nonce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce) - not username/password - that you can even hash/sign or otherwise secure with the current session so that you can automatically log in any user you've authenticated in your custom action. I don't know if sending the nonce back and forth between the server and the browser qualifies as a solution to your problem.

And lastly, regarding `PortalUtil.getHttpServletResponse`, I'm not sure what such a response header is supposed to do. If anything, you'll tell the browser the email address, but nothing else.

With these PortalUtil classes and reverting back to the HttpServletRequest/-Response, I've rarely seen them do what someone expected them to. In the portal world, this layer is firmly shielded away from you. But if you want to use it, there's an important distinction: I've written a description in the past about `PortalUtil.getHttpServletRequest` and its sister call `PortalUtil.getOriginalHttpServletRequest` - definitely nothing for this answer, but it might help relate the problem (I hope it doesn't confuse). [You can find it here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9030658/13447).

Comment: Thanks Olaf. I'm trying to add an extra step in the login process for two factor authentication. I'd like the authentication to be done in the actual login hook and not the portlet, which is why I'm trying to trigger the auto-login. Unfortunately, it seems it has to be a GET request. It seems I won't be able to avoid passing some kind of token in the url. Thanks for your input.

Comment: well, make that token a [nonce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce), tie it to the session, ensure you're using https and nobody will be able to use it even if they find it in the logs.