# Liferay 7.3 how to get the parameter values inside a portlet and access in view.jsp

Tags: java, jsp, parameters, portlet, liferay-7

I am trying to get the parameters inside a portlet in Liferay 7.3. If I pass the parameter like:

```
http://localhost:8080/web/guest?name=abhi
```

in a web page, that contains my portlet. So My question is

**Q1)** can I get this parameter inside the Portlet Controller (doView method) when user reloads the above page, by doing something like:

```
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.ParamUtil;

public class MySamplePortlet extends MVCPortlet {

 @Override
public void doView(RenderRequest renderRequest, RenderResponse renderResponse)
        throws IOException, PortletException {

   String name = ParamUtil.getString(renderRequest, "name");
   System.out.println(name);

 }
}
```

Here I am getting a blank for the 'name' when printing.

And

**Q2)** how I check the condition of this parameter in `view.jsp` view file (how to get the class variable value inside the view file) ?

```
<% if(name) %>
  render form view
<% else %>
  render messageBox view

......
```

I want to render different views according to the parameter value.

Answer (score 1):

Parameters to a portlet are typically namespaced - e.g. a HTTP-parameter `name` could be anything to any portlet - and a page potentially has many portlets. All of them might think of `name` as something different: A city, a user, a customer, the currently used computer, a pet...

Thus any form typically submits values that look like (in jsp-lingo): 
`<input name="<portlet:namespace/>name" ..../>` rather than `<input name="name" ..../>`

If you use tags that are portlet-aware, they might do the decoration automagically, e.g. `<aui:input name="name" .../>`.

Utilizing undirected and unnamespaced parameters in the portlet world might generate maintenance nightmares, specifically when you run into your first ambiguous name.

However, you can deactivate the namespacing, per portlet. Or you can manually access the underlying HTTPServletRequest. Both are strongly discouraged. Here's how you shoot yourself in the foot if you like to:

- Set the portlet's property `com.liferay.portlet.requires-namespaced-parameters=false`
- Utilize `PortalUtil.getOriginalServletRequest(PortalUtil.getHttpServletRequest(renderRequest))` (what these functions do - and why you need them both - is [described, for example, here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9030658/13447))

Answer (score 0):

So the ParamUtil will work if the parameter is for the portlet. in this case it seems you want the parameter in the url in general meaning not specific for the portlet. to achieve this you need to use PortalUtil

```
HttpServletRequest httpReq = PortalUtil.getOriginalServletRequest(PortalUtil.getHttpServletRequest(req));
String name = httpReq.getParameter("name");
```

Note im looking for the original request. not the portlet request.

hope it helps

Comment: So How can I pass parameter to a portlet?

Comment: https://docs.liferay.com/portal/7.0/javadocs/portal-kernel/com/liferay/portal/kernel/util/PortalUtil.html#getHttpServletRequest-javax.portlet.PortletRequest- So the code i pasted there is to be put in your doView im pasting the documentation there so you can see the signature of that method

Comment: Note the solution is hacky. but it does what you are looking for

Comment: Yes, It does, thanks. So can I pass a parameter to a portlet without passing that in the url? Or can you tell me the ways of passing parameters to the portlet? that helps, thanks (you can add that in the answer)

Comment: Somehting like this will do the trick http://yourdomain?p_p_id=THE_PORTLET_ID&_THE_PORTLET_ID_VARIABLENAME=value

Comment: Hi, can you answer Q2?

Comment: So what you want is just to pass the variable from the controller to the view? or am i missing something

Comment: Yes, to check the parameter value in the view, so that I can render different views according to the parameter value received.